# How do i stack two Forms on top of each other

Tags: visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer, .net-framework-version

can someone help me im trying to stack two forms on each other and i use the TopLevel command and it dosent comenup with any errors but when i run the broject it dosent show the second form on top of the other form as i would lie it it just shows the first form

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to show the second form. For example:

```
FormSecond.Show
```

Comment: And I tapped on like this because I’m using a Windows form project with C ‘BrowserControl.show();’